# How to set different proxies for different QWebEnginePage instances?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, qtwebengine

We can [set](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setProxy) proxy for `QWebPage` instance using `QNetworkAccessManager`. `QWebEnginePage` does not support this way.

Since QT 5.6 support to add proxy with `QNetworkProxy::applicationProxy()` [added](https://trello.com/c/OG6glAWq/121-expose-proxy-settings). But looks like it's way to set single proxy for all application's `QWebEnginePage` instances.

Is there way to set different proxies for different `QWebEnginePage` instances?

Comment: did you happen to find any workaround?

Comment: @Midhun, I didn't check if something changed in QT 5.8, but according to this thread there's still no way to do it: https://forum.qt.io/topic/75058/different-proxy-for-each-qwebengineview-instance

Comment: i am wondering if  we just make the tabs as separate process and set different proxy for each process and then load each process window using Window handle to the main process window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. I'm not sure why it's not implemented, but I'd guess Chromium doesn't expose an API to do so.